# 3D Plot measured data from excel xlsx to 3d plot

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, plotly, xyz

I'm trying to convert XYZ values to a mesh or to plot them directly with a function.

I have a table with measured values. The flow of a component was measured at different pressures.  So there are the following measured values:

- Pressure 1:
  X-Axis : Position Values
  Y-axis: Flow Values
- Pressure 2:
  X-Axis: Position Values
  Y-axis : Flow Values
- ....

With 8 different pressures, I have a total of 16 columns with X-Y values.

Actually, I don't imagine this to be that difficult. If you cut the Z-axis (depth) into 8 slices, you have X-Y coordinates for each slice. So the software would only have to connect them linear or with a spline in the plot.

Is there a function to which I assign an X-Y column for each Z value and this can be output as a surface plot?

To make it clearer I have created a small example dummy table with values:

[image: XYZ Values]

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite the answer, because I want to import a DataFrame from an Excel table.
In the Excel table the values are entered as in the picture from my last mail. I would like to plot them in 3D.

I imported the data as follows

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd


fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

df=pd.read_excel('raw.xlsx')
```